# AIX migration stuck on 3% (IBM Power 740)

Tags: migration, aix, ibm-server

I'm trying to migrate AIX 7.1.5.4 to 7.2.0.0. using Base Install iso image.

For exapmle, using this [tutorial](https://sysaix.com/aix-7-1-to-7-2-migration-without-cdrom), I get stuck on preparation step saying progress is on 3% on "Preserving old data" step and it will not go any further.

What could be wrong? I'm using local physical DVD-ROM to perform a migration with DVD-R or DVD+R one layered disks.

I have ASM version 730_149. There is no VIOS, NIM and only one LPAR on the server.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue today, and the IBM tech had me turn on debugging.  At the "Welcome to Base Operating System Installation and Maintenance" menu (with 5 options), type "911" and it should say "BOSINST_DEBUG enabled".  If you continue with the migration from there, it should now show you exactly what it's trying to do while it's sitting there at 3%.